# Java regex expressions

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm using Java 1.7 and want to write some code to detect the presence of a string within another string.
The incoming string will either be one of the the below 2 values:
 - "Install build"
 - "Install my build"

I need to check occurence in a string for 2 possible values. I know I can use an if else but I thought a pattern match would be better as there could be future new values also.

My code is:

```
    String pattern = "(Install)(.*)(build)";
    String option = "Install build"; //see if this matches

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);        
    Matcher matcher = r.matcher(option);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe going to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: [A good place to test regular expressions](http://www.regexpal.com/)

Comment: @MeRose, Please read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). The code should be working before posting at [Codereview.se]

Comment: @holroy: OP's code is a working one. He just wants to get rid of if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is a powerful tool when it comes to deal with String that have an unknown formating (i.e. counting occurences of a certain pattern, or capture unknown subparts of a string, etc).

In your case, using Regexp does not make much sense since you already know every single String possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
Install(?: my)? build
```